# What is the name of this solid?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, terminology

You have a sphere.

Take it and drill a hole along a diameter. You have a torus.

Then rotate the sphere 90 degrees and drill along another diameter. There are now two perpendicular, intersecting cylindrical holes in the sphere. You now have a ___.

Comment: First, mathematicians use sphere to mean the *boundary* of the shape I think you're thinking of, as opposed to the whole shape, and the next shape you describing would usually be called a solid torus. The final shape you get is something that could be called a solid [genus 3 surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Orientable_surface), topologically. I would not expect the specific configuration you're describing to have a name on its own (in the sense that lots of different embeddings of tori in 3-space are still called tori).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $\chi = 1 $ "torus" may be. With a single hole what you are left with is homeomorphic to a torus. Depending on whether there is drilled one,two.. holes we have a doubly, triply *connected* surfaces/solids as 2-torus/ 3 -torus etc. They are topologically characterized by Euler characteristic $ V+F-E-2 =\chi$ that is respectively as solid, Clifford torus,.. $1,0,-1,-2$ depending on the number of drillings done on the sphere. Also it is the genus of surface, the number of handles you add or *connect* to the un-drilled solid.